# Write formula to cell does not accept sys decimal separator / Reginal Format / Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, decimal-point, regional-settings, vba

The sample code below runs fine if windows is in USFormat (decimal = point) but breaks when ran in Dutch format (decimal=comma).

Why?

Is there a way to write the formula to a cell in comma-decimal format that does not require replacing each comma back to point?

```
Sub TestHandleRegionalFormat()

    SourceData = "-.1"

    Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = GetDecimalSeparator
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2) = Application.DecimalSeparator

    If GetDecimalSeparator = "," Then SourceData = Replace(SourceData, ".", ",")

    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2) = SourceData + 1000

    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2) = "=" & SourceData & "+1000"

End Sub
Public Function GetDecimalSeparator()
    'http://stackoverflow.com/a/32992918/4797660
    GetDecimalSeparator = Mid(Format(1000, "#,##0.00"), 6, 1)

End Function
```

USFormat output

[image: USFormat]

DutchFormat output

[image: CommaDecimalFormatOutput]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the formula of the cell using the default property of the `Range` returned by `.Cells(4, 2)`, which is `.Value`.  To set a cell to a formula using the current system locale, you need to use the [FormulaLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) property instead.

This should work:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).FormulaLocal = "=" & SourceData & "+1000"
```