# Converting the decimal seperators in VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem regarding the decimal separators in vba excel . So I have created an app that generates several calculations on my workplace computer. It works fine, but when I try to use it on my personal computer the textbox values always generate the "." instead of the "," which blocks everything. I've tried everything but nothing worked

I've tried the following codes but nothing worked

```
Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
formattedValue = Format(numericValue, "#,##0.00")
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `Application.UseSystemSeparators = False`  like it says in the documentation?

Comment: Yes , it didn't work.

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

UserForm1.dte.Value = "Aujourd'hui , le " & Date
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
End Sub

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application.DecimalSeparator issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152520/application-decimalseparator-issue)

Comment: Try `formattedValue = Application.Text(numericValue, "#,##0.00")`.